# Determine whether the given subset F' of F is a subgroup of F under addition and a subgroup of itself under mulitiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let F be the set of all real-valued functions with domain R and let F' be the subset of F consisting of those functions that have a nonzero value at every point of R.

Determine whether F' is a subgroup of the group F under addition, a subgroup of itself under multiplication.

Can someone explain this problem?

Comment: Can you find two functions in F' that when added together have a zero at one or more points?

Comment: Or, consider what the neutral element in $F$ is. Is the neutral element in $F'$?

Answer (score 2):

$F$ forms a group under pointwise addition, i.e. if $f_1, f_2 \in F$ we define $f = f_1 + f_2$ be the function that satisfies:
$$f(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x).$$
The neutral element in this group is $\mathbf 0: R \to \mathbb R$, defined by $\mathbf 0(x) = 0$, i.e. it maps all elements of $R$ to $0 \in \mathbb R$.

So we ask the question if the subset $F' \subset F$ is a [subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) of $F$. To be a subgroup of $F$, it must itself form a group under pointwise addition. To do this, the neutral element of $F$ must also be in $F'$. Is it?

Over to the question if $F'$ forms a group under pointwise multiplication. I.e., if $f_1', f_2' \in F'$, is their pointwise product $f' = f_1' \cdot f_2'$ defined by
$$f'(x) = f_1'(x)f_2'(x)$$
also in $F'$? You also need to prove the the other defining properties of a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29) are satisfied, e.g. is there a neutral element $\mathbf 1_{F'} \in F'$? Does every element have an inverse, i.e. is there for every $f \in F'$ an element $f^{-1} \in F'$ such that $f \cdot f^{-1} = \mathbf 1_F$?